# AJAX Call - What happens if the user leaves the page before the call is complete?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an app where I make an asynch AJAX call for each page that is loaded, so I can track the flow of a user through the app. Normally the call back to the server to record the visit happens very quickly. However, it appears that on occasion I'm missing some page visits, and I'm wondering if it's because they leave the page before the request is completed.

I know that an asynch AJAX is non-blocking. However, what I don't know is what happens to the AJAX request if the user leaves the page before the request is completed. Can someone help me with this?

If it matters, the service is a C# service.

Comment: How did you find out that you're missing some page visits? Maybe these user don't have javascript enabled in their browsers

Comment: It depends on your php setting ignore_user_abort . If set to false, process will stop executing when client disconnects, if set to true process will finish execution.

Comment: @JonasGrumann - Good question. I test for JS being enabled and redirect them to a new page if it's not. The reason I think some pages might be getting missed is because I see pages being recorded that can only be arrived at from other pages that are not recorded. So perhaps they are quickly clicking a link to go to another page before I'm able to record the visit to the initial landing page.

Comment: I think this is the reason, if you have your tracking code at the bottom of the page or in a $(document).ready({}), it might happen that the user leaves the site before your code has run.

Comment: @JonasGrumann - that is exactly where I have it. Perhaps I need to put the code in the page unload event and make it a synch call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a client leaves the page, AJAX calls will be aborted. The server will not be able to send a response to the client.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that was the case. I'm more interested in knowing what happens to the server process that might already be in progress. That will continue until completion?

Answer (score 1):

If there is time to browser abort ajax request, request never arrives to server.
But once request arrived whether browser closed or not, it is processed by server